# How to properly configure the JDK location in GGTS (Groovy Grails Tools Suite)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I receive the following error when creating new Projects in GGTS running on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks:

```
Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object
withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 
'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
```

Searching here and elsewhere on the internet, the solution is to run GGTS with a 1.7 JDK instead of 1.8 I have 1.7 installed, but my Default Mac OS JDK is 1.8:

Running:

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home
```

Results in:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

A few searches here claim that this is very difficult to change. But my question is: **How can I configure GGTS itself (not the project) to startup with a different JDK?**

When I go into GGTS and go to About > Installation Details > Configuration I see:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk
```

in the output. There must be a way to configure this somehow? I have several 1.7 JDKs installed that I could point at if I knew how.

For what it's worth my $JAVA_HOME is set to:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: I think I have answered by own question. I simply updated the GGTS.ini file to point to the 1.7 JDK. For my installation, GGTS.ini was located in: ~/springsource/ggts-3.5.0.RELEASE/GGTS.app/Contents/MacOS

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if there exists another jdk on the system, you can use others in GGTS. Just add another JDK using Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs . Then at that page click on add and find your JDK location. Finally select the default one for GGTS to use. Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

To customize which JDK the GGTS application uses, update the GGTS.ini file. Add the following two lines to the top of the file:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

For my installation, GGTS.ini is located at

```
~/springsource/ggts-3.5.0.RELEASE/GGTS.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Note that this only sets the JDK that GGTS is running on. You'll still want to update your Eclipse preferences and project settings as necessary.